# Yii2 Custom validation rules before Ajax Submission

Tags: ajax, yii2, active-form

I used to validate Forms before Ajax submission like below because I read "*beforeSubmit is triggered before submitting the form after all validations have passed.*":

```
 $('#my-form').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {

    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myUrl',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'html',

        success: function(e) {

           // do something
        },
    });

}).on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But now I have just tried the same thing with a model with custom validator:

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [

         ...

        [['myParameter'], 'myCustomValidator'],

    ];
}
```

But The Validation seems only to be working with core Validators, but not with customs validator.

Is there a way to achieve this with a custom validator?

Comment: just some ideas: is your 'scenario' correct (maybe rule is not applied)? something like 'skipOnEmpty'? 'myCustomValidator' is incorrectly returning true? here my source of wisdom: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#client-side-validation

Comment: @e-frank The example in the link you gave for the login form is not an ajax submission.